# How to customize ActivityViewController in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivitytypeairdrop

In my application I want to have only 4 option for sharing in activityview controller .

**1.Mail**

**2.Contact**

**3.Whats App**

**4.Facebook**

How to achieve only these 4 options not another one.
And also want to remove `...`  More  option from `ActivityViewController`

Comment: I guess you need custom UIActivityViewController I'd recommend you to follow this link: http://nshipster.com/uiactivityviewcontroller/

Comment: any other solution ?

Comment: if you need customization create the UIVIew and add the custom button/Image for this function